# I am using my main user but not root. However, when I run ls -l in the third and fourth column, I see root. Is that OK?

Tags: permissions, root

I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10. I cannot change the permissions and although I am not using root mode, the 3rd and 4th columns of my listing is root.
Is there any problem?

Comment: columns are permissions, hard-links, owner, group, date & time stamp & filename, so it'll be the 'group' that is root (meaning root user has the root permission as defined in the group bits in column 1)

Comment: I found out the reason myself. I was using symbolic link to a windows file.

Answer (score 1):

When you use symbolic link to a file in Windows and work in that file, chmod doesn't work and everything is in root.

Comment: The NTFS filesystem that Windows uses doesn't store or understand Linux permissions, that's why they have no effect and cannot be changed.